Does dm-crypt waste device space?
That is, when a device-mapping is created manually with the dm-crypt target, is the resulting device smaller than the backing device?
What is the missing space used for?
Will the answer change depending on which crypto mode/algorithm is used?

hi! This is really easy to test, e.g. with an image file that you use with a loopback device (losetup); what have you figured out?

No,
$ dmsetup table | grep mytest
mytest: 0 29360128 crypt aes-xts-plain64 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0 259:45 0
$ blockdev --getsz /dev/block/sdc61 # 259:45
29360128
$ blockdev --getsz /dev/block/mapper/mytest
29360128
$

Ciphers used to encrypt block devices don't require any extra space for storing metadata.
It is at the cost of the device not being protected from data tampering (i.e. byte flipping) or replay attacks. One has to also use dm-integrity to have their data protected from being tampered with.
But keep in mind, that in that case dm-integrity will waste some of the device space for metadata. Anyway, it supports putting that metadata onto a different block device, in case it is needed.
